# Searching entries by title's first initial only

Tags: entries, search

We're looking to pull entries from a channel that starts with a specific letter. We've tried using Craft's search option, with `'C*'`, to pull any title with a word that starts with C. However, it's pulling entries whose second or third words begin with C as well. Is there another route we should consider to achieve this result?

```
{% set myQuery = craft.entries.section('channelName').limit(null).search('title:C*').order('title') | group('title|first') %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're close! According to [the entry on searching in the Craft docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/searching), this should work:

```
{% set myQuery = craft.entries.section('channelName').limit(null).search('title::C*').order('title') | group('title|first') %}
```

Note the format of the search string with a double colon: `title::C*`.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks @steve-rowling! I must have just overlooked this option in the list. Late night coding will do just that :)

Answer (score 1):

Changing `.search('title:C*')` to `.search('title::C*')` appears to work, on my end – the `::` essentially tells Craft that there shouldn't be anything in front of the "C".

Also, for this to work you need to **not** have enabled [fuzzy search](https://craftcms.com/support/enabling-fuzzy-search-by-default) by default.

Comment: Thanks Mats. It does seem to be working though without any changes to our default fuzzy search setting.

Comment: Right, I meant that it works unless you've enabled default fuzzy searching, i.e. the vanilla `defaultSearchTermOptions ` configuration will be fine. Poor wording on my part :)

Comment: I thought that might have been your intent :) Thanks again.

Comment: No worries @NickL. :)